# Reversing queue with array java

Tags: java, arrays, queue, reverse

Hello I was trying to figure out how to reverse a queue with the use of an array. Ive attached the queue class and a the runner class which created the queue and adds the elements inside of it. The reverse method I have creates an array and my thought would be to check the elements remove and add it to the array created. Im new to queue and an a little lost. Thanks for any help an advanced.

```
    public class Queue{
    private int QUEUE_SIZE = 5;
    private Object[] items;
    private int front, back, count;

    public Queue() { 
        items = new Object[QUEUE_SIZE];
        front = 0;
        back = QUEUE_SIZE -1;
        count =0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return count==0;
    }

    public boolean isFull(){
        return count == QUEUE_SIZE;
    }

    public void enqueue(Object newItem){
        if (!isFull()){
            back = (back+1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
            items[back] = newItem;
            count++;        
      return;
        } else 
        System.out.println(
                "Trying to enqueue into a full queue");
    }       

    public Object dequeue(){
        if (!isEmpty()){
            Object queueFront = items[front];
            front = (front+1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
            count--;
      return queueFront;
        }else
      System.out.println(
              "Trying to dequeue from an empty queue");
    return null;
    }

       public void dequeueAll(){
        items = new Object[QUEUE_SIZE];
        front = 0;
        back = QUEUE_SIZE -1;
        count =0;
    }

     public Object peek(){
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            return items[front];
        }
        else
      System.out.println(
              "Trying to peek with empty queue");
    return null;       
    }
       
     public int size(){
       return count;       
     }       
              
    }

     // queue created with reverse method

      public class RunnerQueue {
     public static void main(String args[]){
      Queue q = new Queue();
      q.enqueue(10);
      q.enqueue(20);
      q.enqueue(30);
      q.enqueue(40);
      q.enqueue(50);

    public static void reverseQueue(Queue Q){
         int[] revQue = new int(Q.size);
        While(!Q.isEmpty()){
         
        }
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by reversing the queue? Like reversing the order of how it is inserted? or reversing it once the values are in the array?

Comment: @beastlyCoder oh sorry I meant to put the reverse the values of the queue once in the array. So like the queue will be 10,20,30,40 and after the array or the method it will be 40,30,20,10

Comment: Gotcha, alright

Comment: Collection.reverse(revQue);

Comment: @ShivanshPotdar this wouldn't work because it is not a collection, it's his own queue class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea so far. Assuming all of your queue methods work, such as `size`, `enqueue`, `dequeue`, etc., then all you have do is as you dequeue elements off of the queue one by one, insert those elements from the end of the array towards the start. You can have a counter that keeps track of where you want to insert the element in the array. This counter would start at `Q.size() - 1` since queues follow the FIFO, first-in-first-out principle. Then, with the help of a helper method, you can set the `items` variable in your queue to `revQue` after you've populated the elements of the array with the items of the original queue in reverse order. For example, you could modify your `reverseQueue` method to look something like this,

```
public static void reverseQueue(Queue Q){
    int[] revQue = new int[Q.size()];
    int i = Q.size() - 1;
    while(!Q.isEmpty()){
        revQue[i] = Q.dequeue();
        i--;
    }
    Q.setItems(revQue);
}
```

And this is what the `setItems` method would look like, added to your `Queue` class,

```
public void setItems(Object[] items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.QUEUE_SIZE = items.length;
    this.front = 0;
    this.back = items.length - 1;
    this.count = items.length;
}
```

Just a note that the `setItems` method here assumes perfect circumstances, meaning that the `items` parameter passed in has a valid element at each spot within the array. For the `reverseQueue` method, this should work assuming that your other queue methods work as intended. But keep in mind that the `setItems` method can cause problems if you pass in an array with gaps in it; for example, null elements at certain indices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the update class:

```
public class Queue
{
    private int QUEUE_SIZE = 5;
    private Object[] items;
    private int front, back, count;

    public Queue() {
        items = new Object[QUEUE_SIZE];
        front = 0;
        back = QUEUE_SIZE -1;
        count =0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return count==0;
    }

    public boolean isFull(){
        return count == QUEUE_SIZE;
    }

    public void enqueue(Object newItem){
        if (!isFull()){
            back = (back+1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
            items[back] = newItem;
            count++;
            return;
        } else
            System.out.println(
                    "Trying to enqueue into a full queue");
    }

    public Object dequeue(){
        if (!isEmpty()){
            Object queueFront = items[front];
            front = (front+1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
            count--;
            return queueFront;
        }else
            System.out.println(
                    "Trying to dequeue from an empty queue");
        return null;
    }

    public void dequeueAll(){
        items = new Object[QUEUE_SIZE];
        front = 0;
        back = QUEUE_SIZE -1;
        count =0;
    }

    public Object peek(){
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            return items[front];
        }
        else
            System.out.println(
                    "Trying to peek with empty queue");
        return null;
    }

    public int size(){
        return count;
    }

    public static void reverseQueue(Queue q)
    {
        if(q.isEmpty())
        {
            return;
        }

        Object data = q.peek();
        q.dequeue();
        reverseQueue(q);
        q.enqueue(data);
    }

    public static void printQueue(Queue q)
    {
        while(!q.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Queue q = new Queue();
        q.enqueue(10);
        q.enqueue(20);
        q.enqueue(30);
        q.enqueue(40);
        q.enqueue(50);

        reverseQueue(q);
        printQueue(q);
    }
}
```

So the idea is pop the element from the queue, if it has elements. Call the reverseQueue method for the remaining values in the queue, then put the values that were removed from the queue back onto it. Making it in the reverse order.